# GOOGLE PLACE API : abusive use?

Tags: google-places-api

I would like to have more precision about Autocomplete API Terms of Use.

Here's a use case :

The Autocomplete API is used to allow user to enter a city.

I would store the city label, the country one and the coordinates (lat, long) in order to re-use it later : to connect people with the nearest others.

The stored data will be displayed on a Google map or just in a label on the page.

I've read that Google does not authorize the data retention up for 30 days.

Even if each data is updated before the 30 days, is it an abusive use of Google API ?

Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Did you read it in the terms of use? Give a link to the document(s). How can it be abuse before 30 days?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

10.1.3 (b)

Answer (score 1):

OK,

I had an answer from a Google team member.

It's abusive use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a lawyer, so don't take this as legal advice.  It looks like a lot of that terms of service is to outline what you're allowed to do with the free API and what you need the Enterprise license to be able to do.  Basically, if this is a free app that you aren't monetizing, you should be good.  What you read seems to be making sure people aren't utilizing the free API to harvest some data on a large scale.  If you're app is going on the app store and you're making money off of it, get an enterprise license.  Otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Hi Jake T.,
Thanks for your answer! I agree with you about these terms. But I'm not a lawyer too! Now, it will be nice to have a answer from a Google team member ;)